# How to evaluate the x modulo y when x is not an int?

Tags: java, modulo

How to evaluate something like 3/2 % 2?

Got stuck when solving the below problem:

My working:

First execution 
int k = 12/2, k = 6 
6 % 2 returns 0, and so 6 % 2 != 0 evaluates as false, n = 0 
 
Second execution 
k = 6/2, k = 3 
3 % 2 returns 1, and so 3 % 2 != 0 evaluates as true, n = 1 
 
Third execution 
k = 3/2, k = 1.5 
1.5 % 2 ... not sure how to evaluate this and continue?

Thanks.

Comment: `3/2` is int division and gives `1`

Comment: The division operator applied to integers returns an integer, and return the whole part of the number (it strip out the decimal part). Take that in account.

Answer (score 2):

- `k` is of int type, the `k = k / 2` expression is integer division hence 3/2=1, not 1.5
- the value of `k` in first execution is 12, not 6 because `k = k / 2` happens after body of loop
- hence the `k` gets values 12,6,3,1,0 , of which the body of loop is executed four times, of which only 3 and 1 are odd hence `n = 2`
- why don't you try it yourself?
- if you declared values as doubles, the `%` operator would work for doubles - `1.5 % 2` is `1.5`

Answer (score 0):

since k is an integer, it will be rounded down to 1. So, the third execution will return 1%2 = 1

The final answer will be 2